# mysql update column value from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have 3 Tables Y2018 Y2017 Y2016 with **total_revenue** field.

I would like to update Y2018.**5Y_growth_total_revenue**  with the medium value of the 3 tables value of total_revenue.

I tried like this but it does not work:

```
update Y2018 y8 
inner join Y2017 y7  
inner join Y2016 y6 on y7.id_azione = y8.id_azione = y6.id_azione 
set 
    y8.5Y_growth_total_revenue = (
        y8.total_revenue + y7.total_revenue + y6.total_revenue
    ) / 3;
```

Thank You

Carlo

Answer (score 1):

You could try this way

```
update Y2018 y8 
inner join Y2017 y7  on y7.id_azione = y8.id_azione 
inner join Y2016 y6  on y8.id_azione = y6.id_azione  
set y8.5Y_growth_total_revenue = (y8.total_revenue + y7.total_revenue + y6.total_revenue) / 3;
```

or using a subquery if the db don't let change the table invoved  in join

```
update Y2018 y8 
INNER JOIN (
    select y8.id_azione  (y8.total_revenue + y7.total_revenue + y6.total_revenue) / 3 the_avg
    from Y2018 y8
    inner join Y2017 y7  on y7.id_azione = y8.id_azione 
    inner join Y2016 y6  on  y8.id_azione = y6.id_azione  
) t on t.id_azione = y8.id_azione
set y8.5Y_growth_total_revenue = t.the_avg;
```

anyway  sql have also avg() aggreation function and group by for control the  aggregation